# Convert a Long to base 36 in scala

Tags: scala, long-integer, base36

How can I convert a Long to base36 ? Along with your answer can explain how you came to the answer?

I've checked the [scaladocs for Long](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Long) for converting to a different base, and on converting a Long to a BigInt. I saw that [BigInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.BigInt) does have `toString( base )` so a solution could involve changing the type, but I couldn't figure out how.

*Note: I'm new to scala / java / type-safe languages so I could be overlooking something trivial.*

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The class java.lang.Long has a static method toString(long i, int radix) which will convert a Long into a string representation of another base.  "Radix" means the same thing as "base" in this context.

```
val myLong = 25000L
val longInBase36:String = java.lang.Long.toString(myLong, 36)
```

Scala will treat your scala Long value as a java.lang.Long when necessary, so you can always look for methods in the Java API documentation when necessary.   See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Comment: So did you just know that you had to go to java's Long ? I'm trying to get into scala with no java experience and I feel like I don't know where to find answers sometimes... here is what I ended up with: `def hasher(id: Long): String = {
    java.lang.Long.toString(id, 36)
  }`

Thank you Josh!

Comment: @AKnox - A lot of functionality is from Java rather than being replicated; it always pays to check the relevant class there also (if there is one).  Also, that seems like a singularly poor choice for a hashing function, but maybe you mean something nonstandard by "hash".

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to do the opposite? Read from base n to a long?

Comment: @ChetanBhasin java.lang.Long.parseLong(String s, int radix) should do the trick, if you're looking to convert a string in a base to a long.

Answer (score 42):

Staying within Scala language, converting `Long` to a `BigInt` turns out to be simple:

```
var myLong : Long = Long.MaxValue
var myBigInt : BigInt = myLong
myBigInt.toString(36)
```

output being:

```
myLong: Long = 9223372036854775807
myBigInt: scala.math.BigInt = 9223372036854775807
res199: String = 1y2p0ij32e8e7
```

They way I came to topic was as a Java developer and Scala beginner (reading chapter 1 of "Scala for the Impatient.pdf"). The answers above worked but seemed strange.  Having to jump into Java land for such a basic conversion seemed less correct somehow, especially when `BigInt` had all the stuff.  After reviewing scaladoc and the answers above, a few fails followed.

My biggest fail was using `toInt()` which truncates `myLong` horridly. About to give up, the final attempt seemed so simple and intuitive that I almost didn't try it: `myBigInt = myLong`.  Perhaps one day `Long` will be richer and understand `toBigInt`... this was my first fail in the journey.

Comment: This is a better answer. Thnx

Comment: It would be even better if it used val instead of var

Comment: damn! Didn't think there's a variant of `toString` that would take radix as a parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

So you want to convert Long to BigInt. BigInt object has an apply method that takes Long as a parameter. Here is an example in the REPL.

```
scala> BigInt(458982948578L).toString(36)
res11: String = 5uuqlhpe
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, either the method is available on Scala's `Long` or its enhancement class, `RichLong`, or you must search for it on the Java counterpart. The latter happens to be the case.

It could be either on the source type or the destination type, and since `long` is not a class in Java, you'd have to look for it on `java.lang.Long`. It's not on `String` -- look for methods taking `Long` --, but you can find it on `java.lang.Long`, just looking for methods returning `String` on it.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me nail down the process for solving problems on my own, much obliged.

Answer (score -1):

General form

```
def nextInt(d: Double): Int = if (math.floor(d) == d) d.toInt + 1 else math.ceil(d).toInt

def digitsL(base: Int, n: Long, padTo: Int = 0): List[Int] =
  List.fill(List(padTo, nextInt(math.log(n) / math.log(base))).max - 1)()
  .foldLeft((List((n % base).toInt), base)) {
    case ((cum, div), _) => (((n / div) % base).toInt +: cum, div * base)
  }._1
```

(And the reverse)

```
def digitsToLong(base: Int, digits: List[Int]): Long = digits.foldRight((0L, 1)){
  case (cur, (cum, pow)) => (cum + cur.toLong * pow, pow * base)
}._1
```